# Rmarkdown Tint Vs Tufte references missing in the margin

Tags: r, r-markdown, tint, tufte

I am looking at the packages [tufte](https://github.com/rstudio/tufte) and [tint](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/tint.html) which are very nice styled templates for Rmarkdown.

I run the example provided in the [tint](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/tint/blob/master/inst/rmarkdown/templates/tintHtml/skeleton/skeleton.Rmd) link but the references do not appear in the side margin based on the YAML below

Expected References to appear in the side of the margin is

> Allaire, JJ, Yihui Xie, Jonathan McPherson, Javier Luraschi, Kevin Ushey, Aron Atkins, Hadley Wickham, Joe Cheng, Winston Chang, and Richard Iannone. 2019. Rmarkdown: Dynamic Documents for R. https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rmarkdown.

```
---
title: "Tint Is Not Tufte"
subtitle: "An implementation in R Markdown"
author: "JJ Allaire, Yihui Xie, Dirk Eddelbuettel"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: tint::tintHtml
bibliography: skeleton.bib
link-citations: yes
---
```

When i change the YAML to below it appears without any issue.

```
---
title: "Tint Is Not Tufte"
subtitle: "An implementation in R Markdown"
author: "JJ Allaire, Yihui Xie, Dirk Eddelbuettel"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: tufte::tufte_html
bibliography: skeleton.bib
link-citations: yes
---
```

Neither markdown document fails to compile. In fact everything else with [tint](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/tint.html) works as expected with side charts, formulas and comments in the margins as expected. It seems to be just the references.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

having issues with `tint`, too. unfortunately you can't seem to file bugs on github.